# What does this mean exit (main())

Tags: python

I have seen this in a couple of python script I have been reading lately. I have looked at the doc; they only give examples deal with passing a termination value or string of some sort.

I think what this does is call the main method, then exit?

If someone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   exit (main())
```

Please and thank you

Comment: Which line are you more curious about?

Comment: @Chris question title :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will call the function `main()` and when main finishes, it will exit giving the system the return code that is the result of `main()`.

A simplified example where this might be used:

```
def main():
    try:
        doSomething()
        return 0
    except:
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit (main())
```

If an explicit return value is not given in `main()`, the default value of `None` will be returned. This produces the same system return code as explicitly specifying `return 0`.  If `main` returns anything other than an integer or `None` a system return code of 1 will be produced.

Comment: note that `try` and `except` are not capitalized in Python

Comment: You are of course correct.  (Note that on StackOverview you are encouraged to edit answers directly when you see a mistake!)

Comment: Yes, except that StackOverflow does not allow a 2 character edit. I tried. Hence the comment.

Comment: @themaninthewoods you can cheat this check by adding <!-- --> to the edited answer

Comment: I think the real question is: why do we need 1 to be returned if doSomething() does not run properly, since python will automatically produce error report that tells us that doSomething() has issue anyway. In your example, in order to get '1' output to system, we have to do two indentation inside `def main()`, which is not persuasive enough to occupy space with extra indentation?

Comment: @Jason using the exit() function any integer exit code between 0 and 255 can be returned. This can be useful if your python program is being run as part of a larger process where the detailed status needs to be known. This is particularly relevant if you are calling the python program from within a complicated Linux bash script. More information can be found here: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html.  If you are instead only a stand alone python program that is not integrated into anything else you are correct, this mechanism is not needed.

Answer (score 21):

If you execute a Python script directly, `__name__` is set to `"__main__"`, but if you `import` it from another script, it is not.

So in this case, the script is seeing if you're executing it directly. If it is, it calls the `main()` function to perform some work, and returns the return value of the `main()` function to the system via `exit()`. If the script is being imported from another module, it doesn't execute the `main()` function and simply provides the script's functions and classes to the `import`ing script.

This is a common idiom in Python. It allows you to have scripts that are standalone programs, but can also be `import`ed without trying to do work that the `import`ing script doesn't want done.

Comment: When you say, "So in this case, the script is seeing if you're executing it directly," by "script" you are referring to the module in which function main() resides?

Answer (score 4):

Because if main() contains a call to sys.exit() it will exit the interpreter.

The reason for doing this is to use the return value of main() as the scripts return code.

Answer (score 3):

It means run the `main()` function and exit with the return code returned by the `main()` function. It's a common idiom so that, when running a script from the shell, you can reliably tell if it suceeded.

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom is a common way of running code only when a module is run as a script (as opposed to being imported).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an example to the type of scripts mentioned in the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from youtube_dl import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

This is from youtube-dl package where another `main` function is imported from youtube_dl module. Note this is not to confuse with "`__name__` is set to `__main__`" when executing script directly as @Chris pointed out. Overall, `exit(main())`
could be utilized to make the script run neatly.